# SQL 4 week period in year grouping - Shift Start Number

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project in which I need to query an SQL table and return data grouped by 4 week periods. The week grouping is possible using:

```
SELECT (order_week_number + 3) DIV 4
```

to turn the week number into a 4 week period however I've just found out I need to shift the first grouping to stat in July, i.e.:

[image]

I could do this using a PHP if statement however I'm  trying to do this in SQL so that I can just output and use the data straight after the query.

Is this at all possible, I know I can obviously just minus 6 from the current grouping from period 7 onward but this isn't going to work for grouped periods less than 7?

Answer (score 0):

OK, in case anyone else want to do something similar, I managed to get this going with:

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN (order_week_number + 3) DIV 4 >= 7
THEN ((order_week_number + 3) DIV 4) - 6
ELSE ((order_week_number + 3) DIV 4) + 7
END
```

An then limited the query for July of the current year to June of the next year.

Please do correct me if this is wrong/not sensible!